# How can I test for multiple cases using Junit?

Tags: java, junit

I'm looking for a way to test multiple scenarios with a single test in Junit, but I've not found the proper syntax for this.

In other words, I want to write something similar to this Nunit code:

```
[TestCase(3, 2, true)]
[TestCase(2, 3, true)]
[TestCase(3, 3, true)]
public void MyTest(int var1, int var2, bool var3)
{
    ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look into `@ParameterizedTest`

Answer (score 3):

[@ParameterizedTest](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.8.1/api/org.junit.jupiter.params/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParameterizedTest.html) is meant for this. A separate annotation is used with it to provide the data. [Here is the official guide to using it.](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) Here are some examples of how to use it:

### Value source

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = { "racecar", "radar", "able was I ere I saw elba" })
void palindromes(String candidate) {
    assertTrue(StringUtils.isPalindrome(candidate));
}
```

### Enum source

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@EnumSource
void testWithEnumSourceWithAutoDetection(ChronoUnit unit) {
    assertNotNull(unit);
}
```

### Method source

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("stringProvider")
void testWithExplicitLocalMethodSource(String argument) {
    assertNotNull(argument);
}

static Stream<String> stringProvider() {
    return Stream.of("apple", "banana");
}
```

### Cvs source

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({
    "apple,         1",
    "banana,        2",
    "'lemon, lime', 0xF1",
    "strawberry,    700_000"
})
void testWithCsvSource(String fruit, int rank) {
    assertNotNull(fruit);
    assertNotEquals(0, rank);
}
```

### Cvs File source

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvFileSource(resources = "/two-column.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
void testWithCsvFileSourceFromClasspath(String country, int reference) {
    assertNotNull(country);
    assertNotEquals(0, reference);
}
```

### Arguments source

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@ArgumentsSource(MyArgumentsProvider.class)
void testWithArgumentsSource(String argument) {
    assertNotNull(argument);
}

public class MyArgumentsProvider implements ArgumentsProvider {

    @Override
    public Stream<? extends Arguments> provideArguments(ExtensionContext context) {
        return Stream.of("apple", "banana").map(Arguments::of);
    }
}
```

Given your question, `@ValueSource` seems like the closest match to how you want to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Lets - we are solving the Leetcode TwoSum, and writing two tests under single `@Test` annotation

Junit Test

```java
int[] nums = {2, 7, 11, 5};

//second array
int[] second_nums = {4, 5, 7, 9, 11};

@Test
void twoSum(){
 TwoSum twosum = new TwoSum();
 assertArrayEquals(new int[]{2, 7}, twosum.twoSum(nums, 9));

//second test
TwoSum twosum_second = new TwoSum();
assertArrayEquals(new int[]{5, 9}, twosum_second.twoSum(second_nums, 14));

}
```

The class with logic

```java
public class TwoSum(){
 public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target){
 //logic
 }
}
```